# Arquillian: Parallel drone standalone

Tags: selenium-webdriver, arquillian-drone

I have an arquillian drone test class running against an existing web site (no @Deployment), in standalone mode.

I would like to run tests in parallel, as they are expensive tests. If I use methods in failsafe configuration I get an error and I cannout use a runner like @ConcurrentTestRunner because I must use @Arquillian runner.

Any ideas?

Comment: "If I use methods in failsafe configuration I get an error" - configuring the maven-failsafe-plugin for parallel execution is probably the way to go here, but without the error details this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @cocorossello, Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Nope sorry, I quit drone. I'm using standalone selenium now.